# How to view hardware monitor events in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, event-log

I am wondering if there is a log somewhere in Windows to tell me when my monitor turns on and off. Occasionally it turns off for a few seconds and then back on, and as the reasons could be plenty, I was hoping to find it in the Event Log to investigate what causes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to see if an event is written in the log for a display or graphics issue is to note the time it occurred and then view *all* events. The Windows 10 *Event Viewer*, though, presents many disparate logs in an hierarchical view, making it difficult to find an event at a particular time.

Try a third-party tool, such as Nirsoft's free [Full Event Log View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html), which shows a "flattened" view of all events, and provides search options, so you can restrict the view to the time of the event, and perhaps a minute prior, to see the chain that led to the
"blink".
[image: Nirsoft's Full Event Log View]

Of course, if the issue is in the display device, or perhaps it's power source, that would likely *not* be kept as an Event Log item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try that. Is there is a way to filter by display and graphic issues, or time is the only thing I can use?

Comment: Once you know the event ID's, found by using the time the event occurred, you can search by ID, provider, channel, key word(s) in description, etc. See the image of the dialog above.